# Do embed shortcode on wordpress ajax request

Tags: shortcode, ajax, embed

The plugin I'm editing currently includes WordPress via `include("../wp-load.php")`

When I attempt to use `do_shortcode`, it parses out the embed shortcode without replacing it with the embed code.

When using this method:

```
global $wp_embed;

$content = $wp_embed->run_shortcode($content);
```

It wraps the YouTube URL with an anchor tag rather than the embed code.

How can I use the embed shortcode from an AJAX call that works from including `wp-load.php`?

Comment: Any chance you could share more of your code along with a example of what it's giving you?

Comment: you are probably doing ajax wrong, but it is impossible to say anything else without seeing your code